# How to localize @Messages annotations in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, localization, internationalization, netbeans-7, netbeans-platform

I would like to use the `@Messages` annotation in NetBeans to simplify localization in my application. However, I can not find any information about how to add translations (bundles) for other languages using this mechanism.

Example of an action using the `@Messages` is as follows

```
@ActionID(category = "category",
id = "AddAction")
@ActionRegistration(iconBase = "actions/action-icon.png",
displayName = "#CTL_AddAction")
@ActionReferences({
    @ActionReference(path = "Menu/Shapes", position = 160),
    @ActionReference(path = "Toolbars/Shapes", position = 5133)
})
@Messages("CTL_AddAction=Add Action")
```

How can I get the Add Action to vary depending on the language?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-util/org/openide/util/NbBundle.Messages.html

The @Messages annotation will generate a Bundle.java class and a Bundle.properties file. The Bundle.java class will include functions for localizing, and the Bundle.properties file contains the key-value pairs that determine the exact strings for the root locale.

In order to properly localize, you should examine the Bundle.properties file, and then create a Bundle_fr.properties file (for french) or a Bundle_whatever.properties file where 'whatever' is the locale you wish to add.

Then, when the locale is set for your application, the Bundle.java class should use the correct Bundle_xx.properties file to localize your calls to the Bundle.java class functions.

```
package com.testmodule;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import org.openide.awt.ActionID;
import org.openide.awt.ActionReference;
import org.openide.awt.ActionReferences;
import org.openide.awt.ActionRegistration;
import org.openide.util.NbBundle.Messages;

@ActionID(category = "category",
id = "com.testmodule.AddAction")
@ActionRegistration(iconBase = "com/testmodule/action-icon.png",
displayName = "#CTL_AddAction")
@ActionReferences({
    @ActionReference(path = "Menu/Shapes", position = 160),
    @ActionReference(path = "Toolbars/Shapes", position = 5133)
})
@Messages({
    "CTL_AddAction=Add Action"
})
public final class AddAction implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.FRENCH);
        System.out.println("I am action "+Bundle.CTL_AddAction());
    }
}
```

My Bundles look like:

```
Bundle.properties
    OpenIDE-Module-Name=testmodule
Bundle_fr.properties
    OpenIDE-Module-Name=french testmodule
    CTL_AddAction=Ajouter une action
```

Comment: the Bundle.properties exists. It contains other i18n texts as well. I have added a localized properties file, however the text picked up is the default language, even though other texts which use NbBundle pick up the correct locale text. Would you happen to have a working example I could compare against?

Comment: Just making sure... Are you using the Bundle.java accessors to obtain your localized string? It should look like Bundle.CTL_AddAction()

I'll work on an example...

Comment: The code I am looking to replace is @Messages({
    "CTL_AddAction=Add Action"
}). I expect that the "Add Action" will automagically will be replaced by a locale version, but it isn't. So either I don't understand the magic, or I am not doing it properly. I have a localized text in Bundle_fr.properties but it doesn't get picked up. I do not know how else to specify the message using annotations. Perhaps, there is something obvious I am missing...

Comment: I have added the contents of my Bundle.properties files, as well as a line to set the default locale when the action is performed. What you see in my answer at this point is working for me. First my action is displayed as Add Action (default locale = en which directs to the default bundle.properties) and then once I perform the action the locale is changed and so does the log and the action display text.

Comment: thanks. I think the mistake I was making was that I had the actions defined in a sub package, and I was expecting it to lookup the Bundle.properties file of the base backage. So I created a new Bundle.properties in the package, added the OpenIDE-Module-Name property, rebuilt and it works. Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: Ah I understand. Actually I am dealing with a similar issue with my Bundle organization: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11416375/779982