# Correct java.util.ResourceBundle Organization

Tags: java, inheritance, internationalization, module, resourcebundle

I have an internationalized project with many modules. Each module has its own set of bundles:

```
- database-module
    + com_naugler_project_database.properties
    + com_naugler_project_database_fr.properties
- mapping-module
    + com_naugler_project_mapping.properties
    + com_naugler_project_mapping_fr.properties
```

However, many of the internationalized terms are redundant (such as 'OK' or 'Cancel') and I would like have these terms in one place for easier maintenance and development.

I found [this helpful explanation](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Intl/ResourceBundles/) of ResourceBundle inheritance, but it appears as though a (not?) common ancestor would not be internationalized properly because:

```
- common-module
    + com_naugler_project.properties
    + com_naugler_project_fr.properties          <-- this is not an ancestor
- database-module
    + com_naugler_project_database.properties
    + com_naugler_project_database_fr.properties <-- of this
```

Am I way off base with my bundle organization? What is the right way to provide a common internationalized ancestor?

Comment: After posting I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2067336/779982 but I would still like some feedback...

Comment: To emulate resource bundle inheritance, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4615268/59087

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want seems to be the hierarchy of Resources, that is, you probably want one class to derive from over (or being composed of some specific part and some common part).

Basically, ResourceBundle was not designed for it, and you are on your own.

But you want some advice, I suppose.

- Make sure that common terms are ***really*** common. That is things like "OK", "Cancel", "Next >", "< Previous", "Open", "File", etc. will have common translations in their context. I mean it is fairly safe to translate such standard items only once, but if you want to use them in different context, you still need another entry. Why? Because "Open" button translation would be different than "Open" dialog title translation in quite a few languages.
- Move all the .properties files to one place (for example a directory called "resources"). Of course module-specific files should be separated to different subdirectories...

  - Create a resource factory that will return an instance of the ResourceBundle class (or your own Facade - this approach will actually let you share some common bundle).
- The good practice for large applications is to create some Language Pack, that is to separate language resources to their own directories (i.e. /resources/en, /resources/fr, /resources/zh-Hans). The problem with this approach, however would be the fact that you would need to implement resource fallback by yourself (with the aid of an article you mention in the question, the hierarchy is actually resource loading hierarchy). That means some special cases like falling back from language tag "nb" to "no" but not falling back from "nn"; falling back from "zh-CN" and "zh-SG" to "zh-Hans" and then to "zh" but falling back from "zh-HK" and "zh-TW" and "zh-MO" to "zh-Hant" and then to your default language, not falling from "pt-BR" to "pt" (falling back to default language instead).

Seems like a lot of work? Well, but the maintenance work afterwards would be minimal.

One thing might come in handy [PropertyResourceBundle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PropertyResourceBundle.html) have two constructors that will let you load whatever properties file you want, namely: [PropertyResourceBundle(InputStream stream)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PropertyResourceBundle.html#PropertyResourceBundle(java.io.InputStream)) and [PropertyResourceBundle(Reader reader)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PropertyResourceBundle.html#PropertyResourceBundle(java.io.Reader)). Honestly, in large projects standard ResourceBundle mechanism has too many limitations, so you really need your own resource access layer...

Comment: Excellent yet disappointing answer, thank you. #1 is a very good point, I had not fully considered that. #3 is probably very close to what I will end up doing (subclassing resourcebundle to alter the method for determining candidate bundle names).

Comment: @naugler: The problem with subclassing ResourceBundle is some methods are final. It is stupid, but I can't help it.

Answer (score 1):

As Paweł Dyda indicated, resource bundles on their own do not support class hierarchy resolution. However the [Rincl](http://rincl.io/) project, which my company just released, should do just what you're looking for---and handle UTF-8 `.properties` files and XML properties files as well. It even does message formatting for you on the fly.

As explained in the in the [Rincl quick start](http://rincl.io/#quick-start), you can simply implement `Rincled` and then call `getResources()`; Rincl will load your resource bundles even if declared in a parent class or interface:

```
public class MyClass extends BaseClass implements Rincled {
  …

    final String userName = "Jane Doe";
    //Retrieve the formatted user label based upon the current locale.
    //en-US: "Settings for user Jane Doe."
    //pt-BR: "Definições para usuário Jane Doe."
    final String userLabel = getResources().getString("user-label", userName);
  …
```

Rincl is available at http://rincl.io/ with an [intro](http://rincl.io/intro) and even a full [lesson](http://rincl.io/learn) on Java internationalization. There are many new features coming up, but the latest version should already work for you. Let me know if you have any questions or problems.